# A mysql function that captures error and prompt for continue or not for each line in a query in shell script form?

Tags: mysql

a shell script that runs and can find error in a particular line of  Mysql script and ask to continue or to stop

```
DECLARE @quer VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE q VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE sqlprompt VARCHAR(10)
@quer=SELECT * stg_country
create function sql_query(@quer) 
{
    $q = mysql_query(@quer);
    if(!$q) 
     {  PROGNAME=$(basename $0)
        SELECT  "{PROGNAME}: ${1:-"Unknown Error"}" 1>&2;
          $sqlprompt=SELECT "Do you want to continue..?(Yes/No)"
     if($sqlprompt='Yes')
        BEGIN 
          SELECT "Skipped" AS "";
         exit 0;
        END;
     else   
       exit 1;
    }
      else
      {
       return $q;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: yes i just need a example for the above question..not necessarily regarding code

Comment: You can't use shell commands inside a SQL function.

Comment: You seem to be mixing 3 languages: SQL function, shell, and PHP.

Comment: i know i'm making some wrong concept in place but ,can i get the sql function for error catching and prompt for confirmation ,then i add that function to shell script,as i just got stucked and not finding any solution for this...please help